# Linearization of a Second Order Nonlinear Differential Equation

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, linearization

I am in need of help with the linearization of [this equation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zkdCE.png) around the initial condition u=pi

My main confusion lies in the middle term .5*xdot*x. I cannot for the life of me figure out what to do with this term when linearizing.

Comment: Would you please, show us the involved differential equation?

Comment: apologies, I hadn't quite figured out the image pasting technique

Comment: That's why you should use mathjax to write formulas. Also, did you start with the first hint, have you found the equilibrium point around which you have to linearize?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint.

This system can be arranged as

$$
\cases{
\dot x_1 = x_2\\
\dot x_2 = -\frac 12 x_1x_2-\arctan(x_1)+u
}
$$

or $\dot X = f(X)+U$ with $X=(x_1,x_2)^T$ and $U = (0,u)^T$ . Now assuming an operating point at equilibrium $(\dot x_1=\dot x_2 = 0)$ and  $p_0 = \{X_0,U_0\}$ such that $f(X_0)+U_0=0 $ we have

$$
f(X) = f(X_0) + \nabla f(X_0)\delta X+O(\|\delta X\|^2)
$$

or

$$
\delta f(X) = \nabla f(X_0)\delta X+O(\|\delta X\|^2)
$$

and finally the linearized system around $p_0$

$$
\delta X' = \delta f(X) +\delta U = \nabla f(X_0)\delta X+\delta U
$$

Here $\delta X = X-X_0$ and $\delta U = U-U_0$